# Use NoSQL on a single box

Tags: cassandra, redis, nosql

I am designing a software that will be deployed to one single server. I will have about 1TB data and there will be more writing than reading.

I have an option to buy a good server. I also have an option to use Redis and Cassandra. But I cannot do both. I doubt if it makes sense to run NoSQL on one single node. Will I get enough speedup over traditional SQL database?

Comment: I am comparing NoSQL database with SQL database on a single server. I have the impression that NoSQL gains performance when it scales to a lot of servers. So if NoSQL doesn't have an edge on a single server, we would just use SQL server, which is more stable and matured.

Answer (score 1):

This type of questions is very problematic as it calls for an opinion, which is at most cases highly subjective.

I cannot speak on Cassandra's behalf for better or worse.

Redis is an in-memory solution - that basically means that whether reading or writing, you'll get the best performance available today. It also means that your 1TB of data will need to fit in that one good server's RAM. Also note that you'll need additional RAM to actually operate the server (OS) and Redis itself. Depending on what/how you do, you could end up with a RAM requirement of up to x2.5-3 the data's size. That means ~4TB of RAM... and that's a lot.

If the single server requirement isn't hard, I'd look into loosing it. Any setup, Redis or not, will not offer any availability off a single box. If you use a cluster, you'll be able to scale easily using cheaper, "less good" ;), servers.

Comment: up for pointing out that is is virtually impossible to have that much data in Redis on a single box...

Comment: Thanks - using a single box is rarely a good idea anyway IMO, too fragile.

Answer (score -1):

If there will be more writing than reading then redis is probably not your answer.

Cassandra will handle heavy writes pretty well, but the key question is: do you know your read queries ahead of time? If so, then Cassandra is a good solution. However, if you plan to do ad-hoc querying then Cassandra is not the answer. This last point is actually the key one.

Comment: I believe that's not entirely accurate - I'm under the impression that Redis will outdo Cassandra in any scenario, but I may be wrong here.

Comment: I agree with the other comment disagreeing with this answer.  Redis has very fast writes, the obvious problem is that need for multiple terabytes of RAM if OP uses Redis.